# Searching Outlook returning incorrect results

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

In Outlook 2010, I am searching for this:

> "IATRIC-SCZ5"

It returned about 22 results, all which do not contain this string at all (even in emails that have no attachments, or plaintext emails). Perhaps it's returning "Iatric" messages for some reason, which is incorrect.

EDIT: Yes, Outlook is being Indexed

Am I missing something? How do I search for what I'm looking for exactly?

Here is a sample email that should show up:

> The server blah blah IATRIC-SCZ5 test

If I search for:

> "server" AND "blah"

It shows up.

If I search for:

> "IATRIC" AND "SCZ5"

It does not show up. If I search for `IATRIC` it shows up, but that is too general of a search.

Comment: Have the contents of the mailbox been indexed? Try it again with the following search term: "IATRIC" AND "SCZ5"

Comment: @PFitz Yeah I think it's indexed. How can I verify? I tried your example, but it found 0 results (when `IATRIC-SCZ5` is in some emails)

Comment: In Windows 7: Control Panel > Indexing Options. Look for Microsoft Outlook in the list of "Included locations."

Comment: @PFitz Ah yes, it's being Indexed. Always has been.

Comment: Test a few other search terms. If you're finding consistently invalid results, go back into the indexing options, click the "Advanced" button and rebuild the index.

Comment: @PFitz The results are accurate in normal words (one word, no dashes, etc). Is there something special I have to do to handle a dash, maybe?

Comment: Do you get valid results when searching for just "IATRIC"? When not in quotes, the hyphen will be interpreted as a minus sign, meaning that emails containing the term following the hyphen will be excluded from the results. But that doesn't explain why searching the terms w/o the hyphen yielded zero results.

Comment: @PFitz I did some more testing, see OP. The email does show up if I search for normal words in the email (so the email is searchable and indexed already).

Comment: Using advanced search, try searching the message fields only for the same terms. It looks like you're not the only one to experience this issue: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-outlook/searching-in-outlook-for-hyphenated-numbers/6db19bab-ca1f-49a5-8501-dab887687880

Comment: @PFitz Advanced Search might be working, but it's hard to tell. It doesn't tell me it's currently searching, or if it's done. The `Stop` button becomes lit for 1sec then becomes disabled, and results roll in "randomly" later...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20697/discussion-between-p-fitz-and-jburace).

Comment: @PFitz My workplace blocks all "chat" category sites and subdomains sadly. I might be good though, this Advanced Search just doesn't tell me when it's done

Comment: Go into the File tab and click Options. Select "Search" on the left side of the Options window. Uncheck the box that says "When possible, display search results as the query is typed."